# What needs to be configured (on CM) when removing session preview for Experience Manager?

Tags: experience-manager, session-preview

I want to use Experience Manager without session preview enabled. I simply removed the oData endpoint and staging website URLs from the Publication Target Session Preview tab (and restarted IIS) but I get errors now when clicking Finish Editing:

*Unable to preview the page. There is no publication target defined for this SiteEdit enabled website. Contact your SDL Tridion administrator.*

What am I missing? I am sure I have seen Experience Manager without Session Preview before...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you go to the SDL Tridion dashboard and then choose the Settings, under Inline Editing you will find the Session Preview Settings. Here you can disable the Session preview, which will disable the Update preview button in the Experience Manager view.

[image: Deisable Session Preview]