# Update Preview Button Behavior

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

I can see [how to disable Session Preview](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/213/46), but want to confirm what the Update Preview button should do when Session Preview is disabled.

For example, by default the button flashes when Experience Manager detects out-dated content on the viewed page. Pressing Finish Editing (and refreshing the page) or Publishing will stop this notice and pressing the button will also update content if Session Preview is set up.

When Session Preview is off, should the button act differently?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If Session Preview is turned off from the Dashboard, then the Update Preview button becomes disabled.

[image]

As a user, this is inline with my expectation.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot confirmation and well-placed pun. :-)